# How do you list only accounts numbers and account names under an AWS organization using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-organizations

Using the AWS CLI, how do I output a list of all the accounts with just Account Names and Account Numbers?

The below command outputs Account Names and Numbers along with other values, how do I filter this?

```
aws organizations list-accounts
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below command outputs Account names and Account numbers in a tabular format -

```
aws organizations list-accounts --query 'Accounts[*].[Name, Id]' --output table
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                            ListAccounts                            |
+----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|  alphabet-finance-dev                              |  80XX00000001 |
|  alphabet-security-prd                             |  80XX43500061 |
|  alphanet-devops-tst                               |  50XX00000046 |
|  ................                                  |  ............ |
+----------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

For output in text -

```
aws organizations list-accounts --query 'Accounts[*].[Name, Id]' --output text
```

For output in JSON -

```
aws organizations list-accounts --query 'Accounts[*].[Name, Id]' --output json
```

For output in YAML -

```
aws organizations list-accounts --query 'Accounts[*].[Name, Id]' --output yaml
```